# Restrict CodeIgniter to create thumbs

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am new to **codeigniter**, i am implementing the functionality to **upload images into a directory,** i am successfully able to upload the images, but at the time of upload its also creating thumbs for the images, by creating a directories like **140_140** and appending the directory name with the name of images for thumbs.

My controller is like below

```
$config['upload_path']   = './uploads/gallery/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size']      = '0';
$config['create_thumb']  = false;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    if (basename($_FILES['image' . $i]['name'] != ''))
    {
        $this->upload->do_upload('image' . $i);
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $description = $this->input->post('image_desc' . $i);
        $image_url = $this->input->post('image_url' . $i);
        $this->adminmodel->save_image($upload_data['file_name'], $id, 2, $upload_data['raw_name'], $description, $image_url);
    }
}
```

Can any body please help.

Thanks

Comment: please post the full function

Comment: Check the tutorial here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

It is working perfectly fine, without creating any thumbnails. It does not have any preference such as `create_thumb`. Might be you are  using an older version.